# What is the difference between ffmpeg, ffmpeg wasm, and ffmpeg in native app?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, ffmpeg, webassembly, fluent-ffmpeg

We are implementing a web browser that processes videos using ffmpeg.
I heard that there is a way to implement it on the server side, use native app, or wash it because the browser cannot perform ffmpeg for node.
Can I know the difference between these three?

Comment: I google it but there isn't anything particular, so i follow this thread with curiosity...

Answer (score 3):

- **wasm**: video is processed in the user's browser (the video does not need to be uploaded to the server in order to process it)
- **native**: video is uploaded to server, then processed by the native ffmpeg cli binary in a subprocess created by the server application (then uploaded back to the client if desired)
- **server**: this is a very generic description, so I can't explain without more details, but it would be some kind of abstraction on top of the *native* option (like [ORM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object%E2%80%93relational_mapping) for working with a database)